# Pulling content from Instagram using just cUrl

Tags: php, authentication, curl, instagram-api

I am trying to show Instagram content from a user (mines) on a website. My client-side page would make an AJAX request to my server-side script, which in turn, would do the necessary stuff to pull the content from Instagram API (using cUrl) and send back a JSON response.

Sadly, I am little bit confused with the [Authentication instructions](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/), particularly **Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL**.

In order to get an `access_token` to work with the API, I need to pass `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, and `code`. I have the `client_id` and `redirect_uri`. The problem is the last item, `code`, which gets found after redirecting from `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`. The redirected page will be `REDIRECT-URI?code=CODE` which has the `CODE` to use to make the request to get the `access_token`.

Is there a way to "automate" this last part ? Or more precisely, is it possible to make a request (using cUrl) and then grabbing this `CODE`

Hopefully, this is clear. Unlike other APIs, Instagram seems to make things difficult. My goal is so that when users come on the page, they will see a gallery of images from my Instagram account. They shouldn't need to log into Instagram or do anything to see these images.

**Edit**

```
$clientId = 'XXX';
$clientSecret = 'YYY';
$redirectUri = 'ZZZ';

// step 1: authorize
$url = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={$clientId}&redirect_uri={$redirectUri}&response_type=code";

try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(  
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url
    ));
    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    // how to get CODE from response?

    curl_close($ch);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: please include your code so we can help you

Comment: I've posted relevant code.

Comment: I don't think you understand `OAuth 2.0` what you are attempting to do is incorrect.  You have to send the user to `$url` in their browser window, they will be prompted to login/authorize your app.  Once they authorize your app they will be returned to your `redirect_uri` with the `code` attached. You will then use a `CURL` request to obtain a `token`

Comment: NOTE: Since you want to show `your` photos you only need to do this once to obtain a `token` which you will then save and use to access the api to get your photos. You `do not` need every user to authenticate your app unless you want to access `their` photos.

Comment: But according to their doc, the token may expire. So would I have to get another `code` to get another `access_token`? That's really what I am concerned about as I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What you are trying to do there , is to use the OAuth , I don't think you will need that to grab your pictures

Comment: as per the docs `Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or Instagram expires the token after some period of time. If the token is no longer valid, API responses will contain an “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException”. In this case you will need to re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token.
In other words: do not assume your access_token is valid forever.` there is no expiration time, they only time it would expire is if you revoked it or instagram did because you were abusing the api

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot.